# rendering in microsoft edge and IE compared to other browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I am head-banging about an issue that I am running in today: apparently MS Edge and Internet explorer render things similar size as other browsers only when users zoom level is set to `150%` (not `100%`).

Is this me or is this strange?
Check these screenshots:
chrome `100%`[image: chrome windows]
edge `100%` [image: edge at 100%]
edge `150%`[image: edge at 150%]
All images are taken on same laptop screen.

Is there any reason for this or any solution for a front-end developer to change that default to be 100% just like in any other browser?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The rendering engine for Edge is the same as IE's. Only the old cruft was removed and all the new stuff is the same stuff IE would have gotten. You are unclear what we are supposed to be noticing. Also, we don't know if this page, Google's, might not be adjusting itself to the browser. That's why you need to be supplying the code.

Comment: @Rob  there is no code to supply here. this can be checked with any website. the point being that same css for all browsers renders differently in edge/ie. 150% in edge equals 100% in all other browsers. However, I cannot force my users to manually scale to 150% for best browsing experience....

Comment: @suMi Not really appropriate for Stack Overflow; if you're on Twitter, let's talk: [@SampsonMSFT](http://twitter.com/sampsonmsft).

Comment: Are you sure Google does not have different styles?

Answer (score 0):

Does your computer have a high-DPI display? Perhaps some browsers are adjusting their output to the DPI setting, and others are still doing 1:1 pixel rendering.